# Connect to Localhost with Java FTP

Tags: java, ftp, connection, localhost

I'm developing FTP program on JAVA. I'm using Apache Commons Net Library. My Codes are below.

```html
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;
public class ServerClass {
    private static void showServerReply(FTPClient ftpClient) {
        String[] replies = ftpClient.getReplyStrings();
        if (replies != null && replies.length > 0) {
            for (String aReply : replies) {
                System.out.println("SERVER: " + aReply);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String server = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 80;
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "root";
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {
            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            showServerReply(ftpClient);
            int replyCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode)) {
                System.out.println("Operation failed. Server reply code: " + replyCode);
                return;
            }
            boolean success = ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            showServerReply(ftpClient);
            if (!success) {
                System.out.println("Could not login to the server");
                return;
            } else {
                System.out.println("LOGGED IN SERVER");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Oops! Something wrong happened");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't connect my localhost. I want to login my localhost and see my file. 
My errors are below.

```html
Oops! Something wrong happened
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:188)
 at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:209)
 at com.emrecanoztas.ftp.ServerClass.main(ServerClass.java:22)
```

can you help me anybody? Thanks!..

Comment: 1. You use tcp port 80 which is http by default.

Comment: 2. Do you run ftp server locally ?

Comment: yes, I'm using XAMPP so there is a localhost and running

Comment: By default ftp server runs on port 21. Maybe try changing 21 for 80 when setting port variable.

Comment: no, i tried port 21 but it doesn't work :(

Comment: 1. You need to make sure your ftp server is running.
2. You need to know at what port it is running

Comment: do i need to ftp server for this job? i don't know anything on ftp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the settings below.

```html
        String server = "ftp.icm.edu.pl";
        int port = 21;
        String user = "anonymous";
        String pass = "me@nowhere.com";
```

Comment: There is an FTP server running. :D

Answer (score 1):

Questions:

- Is there an FTP server running?
- Is there a message in the FTP server log about the connect request?
- Does the FTP server allow connections from localhost?
- Is the FTP server listening on localhost or should you use the public IP/name of the computer? (check with netstat)

Comment: there isn'y any FTP server on my computer. I just want to connect my localhost. Does it possible? Or I need to install FTP server?

Comment: No, with no FTP server your code will not work. You may try some other server though.
Try 
port = 21 ;
server="ftp.icm.edu.pl";
user = "anonymous";
pass= "me@nowhere.com";

Comment: Sure, you need to provide a valid server to connect to. The program does not get a response otherwise. It's like to deliver a letter to an address which does not exists.